# current carrying coil changes its shape to a circle in a uniform magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

When the coil is placed in magnetic field, it changes its shape to circle.

How does it change automatically?

Comment: why are you suggesting there is no force?  If anything moving charges, i.e. currents, experience a Lorentz force.

Comment: @zerothehero but how does it influences its shape?

Comment: @hitesh Can you add an image showing how the coil is placed in the magnetic field?

Comment: It is placed in a unoform magnetic field with its area vector parrallel to magnetic field vector

Answer (score 3):

$$dF = id\vec{l}\times \vec{B} \tag{1}$$

where $i$ is the current, $d\vec{l}$ is a small element of the wire whose direction is along $i$ and $\vec{B}$ is the direction of magnetic field.

The force acting on a differential element of the wire is always perpendicular to the current $i$ and to the $\vec{B}$.

As the area vector of the coil is parallel to the direction of the magnetic field, $d\vec{l}$ and $\vec{B}$ are always perpendicular. Using this fact, the equation $(1)$ simplifies to,

$$dF = iBdl \tag{2}$$

The above equation tells us that the force on every part of the wire is equal.

Using equation $(1)$ and $(2)$, you can conclude that the force acting on the elements of the wire are equal and perpendicular to the wire element.

[image]

The forces acting on the wire try to stretch it. The wire exerts a force trying to prevent stretching. At one point, the anti-stretching forces of the wire equal to the magnetic force on the wire. A circle is a stable solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a one liner explanation if you know that the potential energy of a magnetic dipole having dipole moment $\vec \mu$ placed is a magnetic field $\vec B$ is given by $U= - (\vec \mu \cdot \vec B)$. Now, a free system always tries to attain the minimum potential energy, which is clearly attained when $|\vec \mu \cdot \vec B|$ is maximised. Thus, if we have a random shaped non rigid closed loop of current in a magnetic field, it will TURN so as to make its dipole moment vector parallel to the magnetic field vector, that is make

$\vec \mu \cdot \vec B = |\vec \mu|.|\vec B|$

Now this quanity will be maximised if $|\vec \mu|$ is maximised, which, for a constant current carrying loop, occurs when the area of the loop is maximum. When does that happen? :)

And there you have your reason for the shape, from a 'energy consideration' point of view.

Comment: By the way, for a spatially varying magnetic field, the loop will not only turn and expand to a circle, but also move spatially. Try to explain why using this logic. Cheers!